# Translating a vimrc to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, vim, vundle

I recently installed Vim for Windows, and I am trying to port my vimrc from Linux.

The bash script in the vimrc I need to make work is as follows :

```
set nocompatible
source $VIM
behave mswin

let iCanHazVundle=1
let vundle_readme=expand('$VIM/bundle/vundle/README.md')
if !filereadable(vundle_readme)
    echo "Installing Vundle..."
    echo ""
    silent !mkdir $VIM/bundle
    silent !git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle $VIM/bundle/vundle
    let iCanHazVundle=0
endif

" required for vundle
filetype off

set rtp+=$VIM/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
Bundle 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete
```

Notice that this basically just checks to see if my Vundle packages have been installed or not(based on the existence of a readme), and installs them if not. I included the first `Bundle` call to give you an idea of how it executes. The only difference in the code below and my original Linux Script is that I replaced all entries to the Linux file system: `~/.vim` with `$VIM` . When I run :echo $VIM in the Windows Vim terminal it gives me the proper path. The script runs, however it always fails to call vundle#rc() and subsequently fails outright for all the `Bundle` calls. Note that I do have the msysGit installed.

**EDIT** 
The mkdir function was actually working and my environment variable was typed wrong into the console. Also, msysGit needed to be upgraded (failing for unknown reasons. Now I am faced with the problem :

```
Error detected while processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc:
line   58:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc
line   62:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete'
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you run Vim? In the Windows console or in whatever terminal emulator comes with Git bash? Can you do `:!mkdir foo` and/or `:!git status` directly in Vim?

Comment: I made some progress after updating msysGit, but now I have another problem when launching vim with the git directory successfully checked out: Error detected while processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc:
`line   58:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc
line   62:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete' `

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the main problem you have is with the line,

```
silent !mkdir $VIM/bundle
```

Using the `!` shell escape, this tires to call the external command `mkdir`. However, this command doesn’t exist on Windows (unless you’ve installed Cygwin or similar and the GNU tools are in your path) and the use of `silent` means the error message is not printed so screen.

To create the directory in any operating system, you can use Vim’s own built-in `mkdir()` function.  The following command using string concatenation (using the `.` operator) to build the directory path should work:

```
call mkdir($VIM . "/bundle")
```

If the directory is created correctly, the following external `git` command should work as long as you have `git` installed and available in your Windows `PATH`.

Comment: The mkdir with an escape bang `!mkdir` actually works in Windows. The problem for me was that my environment variables were not typed correctly.

Comment: @Rice So it does. All these years, I thought `md` was the (only) Windows command to create directories. Thanks for the feedback and update.